# Message The provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" will expire in 15 days

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Message The provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" will expire in 15 days. As a developer how do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 3):

In iOS Dev Center, click on 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' under the heading 'iOS Developer Program'.  Click on 'Provisioning Profiles' on the next screen and edit the provisioning profile.  When you have finished editing the profile and have saved it, download the new provisioning profile and add it to your device.  Delete the old version of the profile from your device.

Answer (score 3):

For me, here's what I did to fix this issue:

1. Click on your project in the Xcode Project navigator.
2. Click on the Signing & Capabilities tab.
3. Click the blue arrows next to Team, and select None.
4. Click the blue arrows again next to Team, and re-select the team it was originally set to.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is going to expire then you have to recreate it and make sure you are using same certificate for editing/Creating Provisioning profile.